# ELK - GROK Pattern for Winston logs

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have setup local ELK. All works fine, but before trying to write my own GROK pattern I wonder is there already one for Winston style logs?

That works great for Apache style log.

I would need something that works for Winston style. I think JSON filter would do the trick, but I am not sure.

This is my Winston JSON:

```
{"level":"warn","message":"my message","timestamp":"2017-03-31T11:00:27.347Z"}
```

This is my Logstash configuration file example:

```
input {
beats {
    port => "5043"
 }
 }
 filter {
 json {
   source => "message"
 }
 }
 output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
}
}
```

For some reason it is not getting parsed. No error.

Comment: Given the format of Winston logs are completely customizable, how to define how a standard log line would look like?

Comment: I would rather not touch the existing Winston configuration, as other systems are using it. I have updated my question.

Comment: Since Winston produces JSON logs, you don't really need to grok it, simply use the `json` codec in your `file` input and you're good to go.

Comment: I cant get it to work for some reason. I have updated my question. If you would take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this instead:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5043"
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charn